# How can I Stop / Start AVG antivirus protection from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, antivirus

I'm writing a batch script that need to stop and then start AVG antivirus protection in the middle.
Is there a way to do that using command line only?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "in the middle"? I assume when you say "stop" you mean exit the application.  True?  Is there some event that you want to use to trigger the stop, or is that simply user choice?  Same question for start.

Comment: Hi David, 10x for your response. My script does some commands, then I need to stop AVG, do some more commands, and then start AVG again. My script is using load of CPU and memory, and I need to stop all background consuming programs.

Comment: In AVG, there is an option to "Temporarily disable protection" which leaves the application itself running. Are you trying to toggle this option or kill the application altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - I think you want something that looks like this.  It's not bullet-proof, but it should get you started.

```
Set myshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim cmd

REM Do your pre-AVG-stop commands here

REM Now stop AVG using the 'taskkill' command.  Note that this command assumes 
REM that the name of the process is "avgscanx".  You should verify that is true.
REM You also may need to play around with the parameters for 'taskkill'.  Run
REM 'taskkilll /?' in a cmd window to see the various options.  You may also want
REM to add some code to verify that taskkill was successful.

taskkill /IM "avgscanx"

REM Do your post-AVG-stop commands here.

REM Now, let's restart AVG.
REM Modify the command line below for your specific use of AVG.
REM And, again, you may want to add some code to verify that AVG started.

cmd = """avgscanx"" /parameter1 /parameter2 /etc"
myshell.Run(cmd,0,true)
```

One final note.  You may want to consider switching to PowerShell, since it is much more powerful and flexible than batch.

Comment: 10x David. I tried before the command taskill with avg process - it refuses to stop. Also - I tried to change the service to manual and then stop it - it fails as well. Seems all the regular option are blocked :-(

Comment: Did you confirm that the name of the process is "avgscanx"?  That was simply a guess on my part, based on reading the AVG help doc.  You can also try `taskkill /F /IM "avgscanx" /T` which is a little more aggressive.  Also, is AVG running under the same user credentials as your script?  If not, then you would need to account for some additional parameters to "taskkill".